# Using CASE and MOD in apex

Tags: apex

Due to trigger logic requirement I need to create a task via apex instead of using a declarative method. What is the best way to do CASE and MOD in apex for the following formula for the due date field? I could just run a workflow on insert of the task but it would be better to just have it all done in one step.

```
 CASE( MOD( (TODAY() + 2) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),
  0, (TODAY() + 3),
  1, (TODAY() + 2),
  2, (TODAY() + 2),
  3, (TODAY() + 2),
  4, (TODAY() + 2),
  5, (TODAY() + 4),
  (TODAY() + 4)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realistically, it'd be easier to use a [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) instead of trying to write out logic like this. First, create a new BusinessHours record that defines which days should be calculated. Next, simply write the following code in your trigger:

```
Date dueDate = BusinessHours.add(
  [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = 'WeekDays'].Id, 
  DateTime.now(),
  86400000 /* One day in milliseconds */).date();
```

Assuming your BusinessHours are specified as open 24 hours for days you specify, and no holidays are defined for the business rule, this will perfectly calculate the appropriate date without counting days or anything. It's also possible to write code to calculate the next date directly, but you can't use a simple case, so it's more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming your formula to apex will be as follows:

```
public static Date getFinalDate()
{
    Map<Integer, Date> dateMap = new Map<Integer, Date>();
    dateMap.put(0, System.today().addDays(3));
    dateMap.put(1, System.Today().addDays(2));
    dateMap.put(2, System.Today().addDays(2));
    dateMap.put(3, System.Today().addDays(2));
    dateMap.put(4, System.Today().addDays(2));
    dateMap.put(5, System.Today().addDays(4));
    dateMap.put(6, System.Today().addDays(4));


    date FirstDate = System.Today().addDays(2);
    date SecondDate = date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7);
    integer numberDaysDue = SecondDate.daysBetween(FirstDate);
    integer remainder = Math.Mod(numberDaysDue,7);

    Date finaldate;
    if(dateMap.containskey(remainder))
    {
        finaldate = dateMap.get(remainder);
    }
    else
    {
        finaldate = System.Today().addDays(4);
    }
    return finaldate;
}
```